# Data processing JSONP on Python 2.7?

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-2.7, jsonp

I am getting this data from provider, for example, http://domain.com/abc.js

```
I = {
        t: '2015/02/02 16:01',
        c: '207.05',
        v: '484.74',
        n: '324.37'
};
```

How exactly should I extract "v" value on python 2.7? I heard this is JSONP and not a real JSON, which seems not a lot of people have experience on this.

Comment: Since format changed, here is what the actual data looks like: http://pastebin.com/3BfzzYnm

Comment: It's really hard to know without knowing the format's rules (e.g. will there always be 4 characters before the opening { that can be stripped?), and how often this format will change. Basically this is what WSDLs were invented for: describing and versioning interface rules, and without something like that, you need to ask the same questions that anyone constructing an interface would.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is designed to be consumed by a JavaScript callback function. There's no safe and simple way to parse it in Python. And that JSONP data looks a little weird to me, since the keys are variable names not strings.

Anyway, if you're feeling reckless, you *could* do this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import re

datastr = '''
I = {
    t: '2015/02/02 16:01',
    c: '207.05',
    v: '484.74',
    n: '324.37'
}
'''

def main():
    pat = re.compile(r'([a-z]+):')
    exec pat.sub(r"'\1':", datastr)
    print I, I['v'] 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
{'c': '207.05', 'n': '324.37', 't': '2015/02/02 16:01', 'v': '484.74'} 484.74
```

The above code uses a regex to quote the keys converting them into proper strings, so that the data conforms to Python `dict` syntax, and then uses `exec` to create a `dict`.

Note that using `exec` or `eval` on data that you don't control is inherently a dangerous practice. See [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by Stack Overflow stalwart Ned Batchelder.

Comment: import re
import urllib2

def main():
        urlreq = urllib2.Request('http://www.domain.com/test.js', headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
        pat = re.compile(r'([a-z]+):')
        exec pat.sub(r"'\1':", urlreq)
        print I, I['v']


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()



______________________________________________

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I_2.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "I_2.py", line 7, in main
    exec pat.sub(r"'\1':", urlreq)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Please do **not** post multi-line code or tracebacks into comments: it's almost impossible to read. The URL `http://www.domain.com/test.js` returns a 404 `Page not found` error. But to get the HTML from a urllib2.Request you first need to open the Request object, eg `handle = urllib2.urlopen(urlreq)`. _If_ that succeeds (which you should check using a `try: ... except IOError` block) you can get the URL's contents as a string with `handle.read()`; the page headers are returned by `handle.info()`.

Comment: If you need more help with `urllib2.Request` please ask a new question (after searching for existing answers first, of course).